# Problem with TreeNodeCollection.ContainsKey()

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I'm creating a plugin for an application which works with a concept of families.
Each Family belongs to a FamilyCategory and each Family contains FamilySymbols.
A nice tree structure like that:

- FamilyCategory (Doors)

  - Family (External Doors)

    - FamilySymbol (Door 2000x1000)
    - FamilySymbol (Door 2000x900)
  - Family (Garage Doors)

    - FamilySymbol (Door 2000x2000)
    - FamilySymbol (Door 2100x2000)
- FamilyCategory (Windows)

  - Family (Single Windows)

    - FamilySymbol (Window 1000x1400)
    - FamilySymbol (Window 800x1400)
  - Family (Double Windows)

    - FamilySymbol (Window 2000x1400)
    - FamilySymbol (Window 2100x1400)

Now I'm trying to build a TreeView representing that structure. I have a list of Family objects and each of them has a FamilyCategory property. I'm trying to determine if a TreeNode with FamilyCategory name already exists and if it does I'm trying to add the Family to that node. If a node for that category doesn't exist I create a new one and add the family there.
Unfortunately the code below always evaluates categoryExists as false.

```
foreach (Family family in families)
{
    string familyCategoryName = family.FamilyCategory.Name;

    bool categoryExists = treeView.Nodes.ContainsKey(familyCategoryName);

    if (categoryExists)
    {
        categoryNode = treeView.Nodes[familyCategoryName];
    }
    else
    {
        categoryNode = new TreeNode(familyCategoryName);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(categoryNode);
    }

    TreeNode familyNode = new TreeNode(family.Name);

    categoryNode.Nodes.Add(familyNode);

    foreach (FamilySymbol familySymbol in family.Symbols)
    {
        familyNode.Nodes.Add(familySymbol.Name);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try replacing this:

```
categoryNode = new TreeNode(familyCategoryName);
treeView.Nodes.Add(categoryNode);
```

by this:

```
categoryNode = new TreeNode(familyCategoryName);
categoryNode.Name = familyCategoryName;
treeView.Nodes.Add(categoryNode);
```

(`TreeNodeCollection.ContainsKey()` searches the `Name` Property, not the `Text` Property)

Comment: Seriously! Can you see that paper bag on my head? 2h wasted and I even read yesterday that ContainsKey searches the Name property. Thanks.